# Declaring an array to use in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search a column for a certain category and then change that category to a different name if the condition is met (if it's the category I need to change). I know how to loop through the column row by row using a single variable however, when I attempt to declare the combination of rows and columns into an array (to speed up the loop) I get hung up. I am new to VBA and haven't used arrays in the past. Below is the code I have so far.

```
Dim myArray(1 To 1000, 3 To 3)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
 myArray(i, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)

 Next i

If myArray(i) = "Category1" Then
myArray(i) = "DifferentCategory"
```

Comment: Just an informative question, using an array is quicker than a loop? For example; (using your question without an array) using a for loop with an if loop inside is slower than your code above?

Comment: Consider the faster `myArray = Range(...).Value2` syntax, defined as `Dim myArray() as Variant`, and accessed like `myArray(i,j)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are inconsistent in your array usage. You don't need to use a multi-dimensional array if all you are doing is getting the name to change:

Assuming that your code is what you have then the following should work:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 1000)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
 myArray(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)

 Next i

If myArray(i) = "Category1" Then
myArray(i) = "DifferentCategory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you want to change the Cell value:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value2 = "Category1" Then
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value2 = "DifferentCategory"
    End If
 Next i
```

Or you want the local variable (`myArray`) changed for further use in your code:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 1000) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000
    MyArray(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value2 
    If MyArray(i) = "Category1" Then
       myArray(i) = "DifferentCategory"
    End If
 Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The following 1 liner will do what you explained in your first sentence:

```
Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1000, 3)).Replace "Category1", "DifferentCategory"
```

Or a more lines easier to read version:

```
Dim targetRange As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1000, 3))
    targetRange.Replace "Category1", "DifferentCategory"
End With
```

As you can see an array is not necessary since you are looking for a value and replacing it.

If you really want to use an array though, this is one of the faster ways:

```
Dim myArray
Dim i As Integer
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'myArray will now be a (1 to 1000, 1 to 1) array with all the cell values.
    myArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1000, 3))
End With
For i = 1 To 1000
    If myArray(i, 1) = "Category1" Then myArray(i, 1) = "DifferentCategory"
Next
```